# Meaning of the verb "to vendor"

Tags: meaning, verbs, technical

Several technical articles write about *vendor* using it as a verb:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#configparser quoth:

> While one could standardize on what Python 3 accepts and simply vendor the backport of the configparser module

while https://github.com/sdispater/poetry#installation states

> Poetry provides a custom installer that will install poetry isolated from the rest of your system by vendorizing its dependencies

Both [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vendor) and [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/vendor) only list the noun vendor, and not the verb.

What do they mean?

Comment: The verb is "to sell." A vendor sells thing. Was the sentence containing **vendorizing** produced by a jargon generator? As far as I can tell: the sentences are nonsense.

Comment: The dictionaries are right. So is Weather Vane. You can't 'seller' a backport or 'sellerize' dependencies.

Comment: @WeatherVane: both are taken from existing software projects

Comment: Spare us from software engineers. They are making machines which will take important decisions about matters of which they are quite ignorant. I know that because I was one. I would supply something for a business, which they were all well trained for, but I wasn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of software development, "vendoring" and derivatives is a made-up verb used in some languages and platforms to refer to techniques and tools to package software dependencies; specifically to import (or make easily importable) trusted snapshots of objects into a project without needing to depend on third-party resources to retrieve them again.

For example, you can think of "vendor" as representing a named local location (eg. a directory called "vendor") for storing assets from third-parties ("vendors" in the normal sense, though they may be internal or external to the organisation), and vendoring as the act of placing items into this vendor repository.

https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25719-go15vendor.md

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vendor